# Выбрасывает на поиск майл.ру при работе на сайте

Tags: поддержка

Скажите, с сайтом проблемы? Когда  нажимаю на вопросы  или перелистываю страницы на сайте Русский язык, меня выбрасывает на поиск майл.ру. С чем это может быть связано? Такая проблема появилась сегодня.

Comment: А как проблему решить, вы не знаете?

Comment: Вирусню (особенно программы от mail.ru) удалите и настройки браузера проверьте. Особенно расширения и прокси-сервер. Также полезно проверить файл hosts и настройки DNS.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я так и сделал - удалил  программы от mail.ru , проблема решилась.